# HTML5 Javascript Canvas Rotate Sprite

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, rotation

I have already looked for many questions like this and his answers on stackoverflow but it seems that I never complety have the exact same problem:

Player, created at x = canvas.width /2, y = canvas.height /2
[image]

The code that I use to generate the various sprites on the canvas is:

```
  class Sprite {
    constructor({
      position,
      imageSrc,
      scale,
      framesMax = 1,
      offset = { x: 0, y: 0 },
    }) {
      this.position = position
      this.width = 50
      this.height = 150
      this.image = new Image()
      this.image.src = imageSrc
      this.scale = scale
      this.framesMax = framesMax
      this.framesCurrent = 0
      this.framesElapsed = 0
      this.framesHold = 5
      this.offset = offset
    }
    
    draw() {
      c.drawImage(
        this.image,
        this.framesCurrent * (this.image.width / this.framesMax),
        0,
        this.image.width / this.framesMax,
        this.image.height,
        this.position.x - this.offset.x,
        this.position.y - this.offset.y,
        (this.image.width / this.framesMax) * this.scale,
        this.image.height * this.scale
      )
    }
    
    animateFrames() {
      this.framesElapsed++
    
      if (this.framesElapsed % this.framesHold === 0) {
        if (this.framesCurrent < this.framesMax - 1) {
          this.framesCurrent++
        } else {
          this.framesCurrent = 0
        }
      }
    }
    
    update() {
      this.draw()
      this.animateFrames()
    }
}
```

Then what I want to do is to create the "Fishnet" that you see in the first picture, and position the image on a certain angle, but keep the starting point of the coordinates, another image is possible useful.

Fishnet:
[image]

I have tried many things, but the most common that I see everywhere, is to draw de image, save the canvas context, translate the canvas, rotate the canvas, and draw the image.

For reasons that I can't get in to, I never could rotate the image and maintain the starting position.

I wrote another sprite class specific for this rotation, and added the rotate method:

```
  rotate(){
    c.save();
    c.translate(x,y)
    c.rotate(this.angle)
    c.drawImage(
      this.image,
      -(this.image.width),
      -(this.image.height),
      150,
      50,
      this.position.x - this.offset.x,
      this.position.y - this.offset.y,
      (this.image.width / this.framesMax) * this.scale,
      this.image.height * this.scale
    )
    
    c.restore();
  }
```

The x and y continue to be the (canvas.width / 2) and (canvas.height / 2) in witch I have my doubts of working...

The angle is calculate by the position of the yellow (projetile) and the center of the canvas:

```
angle = Math.atan2(projectile.position.y - canvas.height / 2, projectile.position.x - canvas.width / 2)
```

One of the few attempts this has """worked""", was by an example that I saw online, but I had to remove most of my parameters on the drawImage as I rotated it, like this:

```
    draw() {
        c.drawImage(
          this.image,
          this.framesCurrent * (this.image.width / this.framesMax),
          0,
          this.image.width / this.framesMax,
          this.image.height,
          this.position.x - this.offset.x,
          this.position.y - this.offset.y,
          (this.image.width / this.framesMax) * this.scale,
          this.image.height * this.scale
        )
      }
```

Rotate:

```
    rotate(){
    c.save();
    c.translate(x,y)
    c.rotate(this.angle)
    c.drawImage(
      this.image,
      -(this.image.width),
      -(this.image.height)
    )
    c.restore();
```

Then I called the Draw method and after the Rotate method. It generated me 2 images. If I only call the rotate method it is obvious that I create only one image, but idk why, can't get the drawImage from rotate to work with the scale and position's x,y. Only works with those 3 paramaters

(this.image, -(this.image.width),-(this.image.height))

Here is the result of working only with the rotate method:

Rotation working with no scaling or proper angle (maybe translate is wrong?)
[image]

It can be a problem only on the angle, and I will try to figure it out (I do not think so anyway, because I have another solution launching a circle at that angle to check if its right, and it is.)

Still can't get it to work with scaling.. like I do in the draw() method above.

I know this will be very confusing but I have little knowledge of canvas in JavaScript (and overall..), feel free to comment on more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using an image why not better draw that fishnet? this question is quite long an has a lot of code, a minimal example will help a lot getting a quick answer .... also if you use a proper game engine will solve a lot of your  https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, you can just draw the net yourself no need for an image, it does not look too complicated, an arc and a few lines should be a good starting point to test the concept

And the most complicated part I see you are already using:

```
    c.translate(x,y)
    c.rotate(angle)
```

Here is a quick example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var angle = 0

function drawNet(x, y, w, h, angle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x,y)
  ctx.rotate(angle)
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.arc(0, h, w / 2, 0, Math.PI)
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-angle) 
  ctx.translate(-x,-y)
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height)
  drawNet(70, 50, 55, 50, angle)
  drawNet(200, 80 + Math.sin(angle)*30, 45, 30, -angle*2)
  angle += 0.1 
}

setInterval(draw, 60)
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid;">
```

In my `function drawNet` I'm translating and rotating to the given parameters then rotating back and translating back to the original position, that allows all following drawing to be at the correct location